# Setting the last row in a given worksheet and copy all the data and paste into another sheet and update a pivot table

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have a third party piece of software that produces an excel file based on a report that I run. It stores the data temporarily in a text file called `reportdata.txt` and then produces a workbook called book1 and the data from the text file is copied into this. I want the VBA to copy all of the data to the last row from Columns A to N and to paste it to and work book called ExcelList in sheet 1. This in turn will be used to populate a pivot table. However the code that i am using is not copying all of the data. And the pivot table does not refresh, Here is the code

```
Sub Auto_Open()
'On Error GoTo ErrorHandler



Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

ThePath = ThisWorkbook.Path
Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThePath + "\ReportData.txt"

' Copy the workbook, and close the source text file (having marked it as saved)
Set Wbook = ActiveWorkbook
ActiveSheet.Copy
Wbook.Saved = True

'copy select bits of ReportData to Student Details and make the latter active


LastRow = Workbooks("ExcelList.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Workbooks("ExcelList.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:N" & LastRow) = Workbooks("ReportData.txt").Sheets("Reportdata").Range("A3:N" & LastRow).value
Workbooks("ReportData.txt").Close
Workbooks("Book1").Saved = True
Workbooks("ExcelList.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

'Recalculate the worksheet
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

' Refresh_Macro Macro
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh

' Mark the active workbook as saved
ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Workbooks("ExcelList.xlsm").Saved = True
'Workbooks("ExcelList.xls").Close

Exit Sub
```

Comment: Where is your Auto_Open macro located, in ExcelList.xlsm or another workbook and at what level is it, on a worksheet , workbook or in a module ?

Comment: Hi braX, the Auto_Open is the ExcelList.xlsm and it is in a module

Answer (score 0):

It's not importing all the data probably because you are using LastRow on the Worksheet

```
LastRow = Workbooks("ExcelList.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

as the LastRow also on your text file.

```
Workbooks("ReportData.txt").Sheets("Reportdata").Range("A3:N" & LastRow).value
```

Try

```
Option Explicit
Sub Auto_Open_1()

    Const TEXTFILE = "ReportData.txt"

    Dim Path, wbSource As Workbook, wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, iLastRow As Long
    Dim rngSource As Range

    Path = ThisWorkbook.Path
    'Debug.Print Path

    Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & TEXTFILE, False, True)
    Set wsSource = wbSource.Sheets(1)
    iLastRow = wsSource.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngSource = wsSource.Range("A3:N" & iLastRow)
    'Debug.Print wsSource.Name, iLastRow

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    'ws.Cells.Clear
    rngSource.Copy ws.Range("A1")
    wbSource.Close False

    ' refresh pivot
    wb.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False
    wb.Sheets("Sheet2").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh

    ' end
    MsgBox iLastRow - 2 & " rows copied from " & TEXTFILE, vbInformation
    'wb.Saved = True
    wb.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks i’ll give that a try

Comment: Thanks that has worked perfectly!! Really appreciate that took me hours of messing with the code and still not getting anywhere!